# Building a square matrix having in the j-th column specific data

Tags: matrices, matlab

Why if we want to build the square matrix $A$ having in the j-th column the ordinates $y_i^j$ in the `y5` vector, we have to elevate every column as it follow:

```
y5 = [-0.0822 -0.2888 -1.3464 -0.8785 1.0000];
A = [y5' (y5').^2 (y5').^3 (y5').^4 (y5').^5];
```

Answer (score 1):

This is done because it is the simplest method to visually see what is happening. The following code is much less efficient, but will achieve the same result.

```
y5 = [-0.0822 -0.2888 -1.3464 -0.8785 1.0000];
[idxMat,y5mat] = meshgrid(1:5,y5); % build temporary matrices

A = y5mat.^idxMat; % perform exponentiation
```

In the temporary matrices, `idxMat` has the vector `[1,2,3,4,5]` repeated in every row and `y5mat` has the `y5` vector repeated in every column.